# Google Sign In button with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I'm trying to create a Google Connection Button with AngularJS.

I'm following this : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I load *platform.js* in my index.html, but this file contains a *ng-view* that display another HTML template.

Then the

```html
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

is not loaded..

Any solution to access to the data-onsuccess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this plugin

https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin

Usage

1. Include google-plus-signin.js.
2. Add directive.g+signin as a dependency to your app.
3. Add  to your app.
4. Create a listener on your $scope for event:google-plus-signin-success to detect when your users are authenticated.
5. Optional: Listen for event:google-plus-signin-failure to handle authentication errors and sign outs.

Example

```
<div ng-app="directive.g+signin">
  <google-plus-signin clientid="620125449078"></google-plus-signin>
  <p>^ This is a Google Plus sign-in button</p>
</div>

  $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-success', function (event,authResult) {
    // Send login to server or save into cookie
  });
  $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-failure', function (event,authResult) {
    // Auth failure or signout detected
  });
```

Comment: I did find it hours ago, but it didn't work.
In fact, now I took the time to explore it, and after some customisation, it works. Thank for your answer

Comment: When using this I received an error that said "online is not defined" and then had to add quotes around online in the code per this pull request... https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin/pull/68/commits/7b6ab8f704ccd7298d01c0e2bacb0a89e6498ab8